# HTTP Get call throws 307 error

Tags: node.js, http, postman

I am trying to make a get call in order to fetch a file hosted on a server . When i make the same call via Postman , it's 200 but when i try to do the same call via Node.js https module it throws 307 error.Can someone please explain why this may happen?

```
module.exports.get = function getAssets(req,res,next) {
    var options = {
      host: "domain.com",
      path: "/api/v2/commid/assets/assId/original",
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'x-api-key': 'apikey'
      }
    };
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
      console.log("Status"+res.statusCode);
     });
    req.end();
    return next();
};
```

Comment: 307 is not an error code. It's a redirect status indication.

Comment: console log your `req` and check request headers and compare it with headers sent with postman